# JAVA ThreadPoolExecutor is can be except main thread core?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

When A.jar program is running in 8core Server,

ThreadPoolExecutor is can be except
about the CPU-core for running A.jar main thread?

or other way out is exist?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, could you perhaps reword it?

Comment: @Ewald hmm simply, ThreadPoolExecutor using all core, i want to use only some of the core. e.g: 1~8 core -> except number 1 core.

Comment: Ah I see! I think I might have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine how many cores the executor will use during construction, so, if you need to limit the executor for any reason, simply pass it a value during construction.  What you want to do, is restrict the maximum and core pool sizes, in your case, you might want to set them both to the same value, let's say four, to only have four cores in use at any given time.

You can not decide which cores are used though, that's outside your control as far as I can tell.

The signature for the constructor most often used is:

ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue workQueue)

Please see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for more information.